# Script to Create Home Drives

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to create a small script that creates a folder on our file server, creates the share, sets the ACLs on the share, then maps the share to their U: drive via Home Folder in Active Directory.

The server is running 2012 R2, the Active Directory PowerShell Module is installed.

This is what I have thus far:

```
$session = new-pssession -ComputerName fileserver
Enter-PSSession $session
$user = read-host 'Input username'
import-module activedirectory
new-item -name $user -itemtype Directory -path "\\fileserver\G$" | out-null
new-smbshare -name "$user$" -path "G:\$user" -ContinuouslyAvailable $true -FullAccess "domain\domain admins" -changeaccess "domain\$user"
Set-ADuser $user -homedirectory "\\fileserver\$user$" -homedrive U:
```

I read using the `Enter-PSSession` command doesn't allow remote commands to pass through, and that instead you needed to use `Invoke-Command -ScriptBatch`.

It is telling me the share is already created, even though it is not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a remote session for any of your commands, provided the [RSAT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731209.aspx) are installed on your client (so that `Set-ADUser` is available locally). [`New-SmbShare`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635722%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) can be run against a remote host using the `-CimSession` parameter.

However, I would strongly recommend against sharing each userhome individually. Instead share just the folder containing the userhomes (e.g. `\\fileserver\userhomes$`) and set the home directory to the user folder below that share:

```
$user = Read-Host 'Input username'

$userhome = New-Item -Name $user -Type Directory -Path "\\fileserver\userhomes$"

$acl = Get-Acl -Path $userhome.FullName
$acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)
$perm = $user,'FullControl','ContainerInherit','ObjectInherit','None','Allow'
$ace = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $perm
$acl.SetAccessRule($ace)
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $userhome.FullName

Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Set-ADuser $user -HomeDirectory $userhome.FullName -HomeDrive 'U:'
```

Enable [access-based enumeration](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd772681%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on the share to present users with only those folders they can actually access.

Comment: Wholeheartedly agree with this, creating a share per user is a really really bad idea.